# making a program of a list of words that doesn't have a "newline at the end"

Tags: python

So I'm making a function that examines a list of words in a file and takes all the words that start with a certain letter and then puts them in a  new file. this is my code so far:-

```
def getListBegin(c,ifile,ofile):
   for word in ifile:
      if word.startswith(c):
          ofile.write(word)
```

It already has built-in open and close functions for both files. this current function lists all the words that start with character 'c' but I'm not passing the test because it says "your program should not end with a newline"

Comment: `for word in ifile` reads a single line into the `word` variable not a word; and the line has a new line at the end of it

Comment: Please provide the error trace, sample data, and is ifile and ofile lists ?

Comment: ifile is a list of words, and ofile is an empty file that stores words with certain starting letters for instance "c". i submit it to a database that automatically opens and closes the files. and it shows all the correct words but lists the error:"your program should not end with  a new line"

Comment: any ideas how to edit it Smac89?

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
 for word in ifile:
```

You are grabbing each line. For example, perhaps you are grabbing

```
 word = "charlatan\n"
```

If it is a requirement that you remove newlines from the words before writing them to the file, then you should strip whitespace.

```
for word in ifile:
    word = word.strip()
    ...
```

If you are supposed to leave all the newlines (so the words are on separate lines) and only strip the newline from the final entry, that'll be a bit more complex. The easiest way might be to just do what you're doing and then do a second pass where you read the file, then write it back without the final character.

Update:

Based on your comment that you must only remove the newline from the final word, it may be useful to load all the words into a list, then only modify the final one:

```
 words = ifile.readlines()

 # now iterate through the list, keeping only the words you want

 # after words only contains the words you want, strip the newline from the final word
 words[-1] = words[-1].strip()
```

Comment: so then the word.strip('\n') would go above the ofile.write(word) ?

Comment: I should add that I interpret your problem as the output file ends in a newline. If in fact, the issue is truly that "your program should not end with a newline", then you should just modify your program so that it doesn't end in a newline. Go to the very end of the program and delete characters until the cursor is at the very end of your last line of code.

Comment: You could put it in a few places. I edited the post to include where I would put it, right after extracting the word from the file.

Comment: doing that gets rid of the new line at the end but instead of listing the words vertically, just continually writes them like :charlatancarcoralcooler

Comment: it turns out its supposed to leave all newlines and only strip the newline form the final entry

Comment: Ok - I've updated the response with a suggestion of one way you could handle that.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are approaching the problem is correct. However the way you have written code you are checking lines and not words.

```
def getListBegin(c,ifile,ofile):
    for line in ifile:
        words = line.rstrip('\n').split[' ']
        for word in words:
            if word.startswith(c):
                ofile.write(word)
```

Comment: Performing 2 sets of iterations for a very simple task is not a valid solution!  Plus, your indentations are wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Given the following text as an example:

```
text = (
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
    "Vestibulum faucibus pulvinar congue. Donec malesuada "
    "scelerisque ex, at cursus ipsum. Sed eros ex, molestie "
    "eget vulputate in, cursus vitae odio. Duis eu nisi dolor. "
    "Suspendisse elit quam, tincidunt in odio in, rutrum dictum ipsum."
)
```

We write this function to extract all the words that start with a given character:

```
def starts_with(text, char):
    import re
    pattern = re.compile(r"\b[.{}]\w+".format(char))
    return pattern.findall(text)
```

Here is how the output will look like:

```
>>> print(starts_with(text, 'i'))
['ipsum', 'ipsum', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'ipsum']
```

And here is the same thing from a list of words:

```
>>> words_list = text.split()
>>> print(starts_with(str.join(' ', words_list), 'i'))
['ipsum', 'ipsum', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'ipsum']
```

If you want to write these in a file, you can do so as follows:

```
selected_word = starts_with(text, 'i')

with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as file:
    for word in selected words:
        print(word, file=file, end='\n')
```

This puts every word found in a new line. You can substitute `end='\n'` with anything you like, e.g. space, tab, etc.

You may also consider writing your words in a CSV. It would be easier to manage in the future.

## Without the `print` function:

To write without the `print` function, you may do as follows:

```
found = starts_with(text, 'i')

file = open("foo.txt", "w")
file.seek(0, 0)
file.write(str.join('\n', found))
```

Now let's test it:

```
file = open("foo.txt", "r")
file.seek(0, 0)
for index, __ in enumerate(found):
   line = file.readline()
   print ("Line No %d - %s" % (index+1, line))

file.close()
```

Displays:

```
Line No 1 - ipsum
Line No 2 - ipsum
Line No 3 - in
Line No 4 - in
Line No 5 - in
Line No 6 - ipsum
```

With no extra lines.

Note that the key here is to use `str.join('\n', found)` to prepare your contents to be saved into a file.

Comment: should be noted that open and close functions are already in system so we aren't to write them in our code. and it says not to use print functions. I just need to make it so it stays in a list of words, which the code i posted does. i just need to remove the very last "newline" from the list of words

Comment: I will modify and replace the `print()`. But note that using iterations for finding patterns in a string is not a valid solution. It is very memory/process intensive.

Comment: Added a solution to write _without_ the `print` function.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you're grabbing newline-terminated lines and writing them to your outfile, so it's expected that the file will end in a newline. Framing the solution as "add a newline at the end of every line except the last" presents a problem, though: you don't know whether any given word you're writing will be the last. Instead, you can try turning it around: add a newline at the *beginning* of every line except the *first*.

This isn't the most elegant, but it gets the point across:

```
def getListBegin(c,ifile,ofile):
    newline = ''
    for word in ifile:
        if word.startswith(c):
            ofile.write(newline + word.strip())
            newline = '\n'
```

The first time you write a word, `newline` will be blank and you'll simply be writing the word to the file without any delimiters. After that, the rest of the words you write will be prepended with `\n`.

Comment: perfect this makes sense actually. and i assume the word.endswith(c) would work as well with this same code ?

Comment: @pythonUC211 `word` still ends with a newline (I only strip it as I'm writing it to the outfile), so you'll either need to strip it before using `endswith` or make sure your `endswith` argument ends with a newline.

Comment: can you clarify that a bit more?

Comment: @pythonUC211 `word` ends with a `\n` character, so `word.endswith('foo')` will fail even if the word in fact ends with "foo", because in that case `word` would actually end in "foo\n". You need to strip that newline off of `word` before using `endswith`.

Comment: anyway you can show me what that looks like? i assume that means i do word.strip('\n') before the if wordsends with statement

Comment: think I'm pretty close

Comment: can't i just do word.strip('\n') before the if statement?

Comment: just need this last one